# How can I write a reusable object to use in other methods in C#?

Tags: c#

How can I write a reusable object that I can use in other methods

```
        select new ObjectDTO()
        {
            Id = linkOne.Id,
            CSTrancheId = linkOne.CSTrancheId,
            DMBalExternalId = linkTwo.DMBalExternalId
        };
```

Is there some way I can write a static method to reuse this object so that I don't have to type it out in all of my methods? For example

select ReusableObject
where ReusableObject is:

```
new ObjectDTO()
            {
                Id = linkOne.Id,
                CSTrancheId = linkOne.CSTrancheId,
                DMBalExternalId = linkTwo.DMBalExternalId
            };
```

Comment: I removed some tags because they're not related to the question. It's not clear what you're trying to achieve, or why.

Comment: if `linkOne` and/or `linkTwo` are instance members (not static), then no, you cannot make a static function.  If you are just trying to define ReusableObject, then make a `class` or `record` with the three properties of `ID`, `CSTrancheId`, `DMBalExternalID`.

Comment: Voting to reopen. The question is not perfect, but its clear enough that it can be answered to a degree that helps the asker to improve it or ask a new (and improved) question.

Answer (score 1):

Not sure why do you need this and what are you trying to achieve but you can have static property in static class - for example:

```
public static StaticExample
{
   public static ObjectDTO ObjectDTO { get; set; }
}
```

And you can assign this object like this:

```
StaticExample.ObjectDTO = new ObjectDTO()
            {
                Id = linkOne.Id,
                CSTrancheId = linkOne.CSTrancheId,
                DMBalExternalId = linkTwo.DMBalExternalId
            };
```

And use it everywhere.

Be careful with static modifier.

Not sure what problem are you trying to solve, but maybe if you could explain it better we could propose some better solutions.